# WPF localization from db

Tags: wpf, localization, localizable.strings

Which is the best approach to localize a WPF application storing resources in the database?

My task is building an application and localize it reading text/labels/... from the database.
The user can add a new Culture adding a column in the table that stores the resources and the application must be able to use one of the cultures defined.

```
+----------------+
|ID   |EN  |FR   |
+----------------+
|R001 |Dog |Chien|
+----------------+
|R002 |... |.... |
+----------------+

+----------------------+
|ID   |EN  |FR   |IT   | 
+----------------------+
|R001 |Dog |Chien|Cane |
+----------------------+
|R002 |... |.... |...  |
+----------------------+
```

ObjectDataProvider could be a good solution, but I don't want to create a different ObjectDataProvider for each text I need to localize.
Is there a way to use the same ObjectDataProvider in different control using a parametrized binding (the parameter is the resource's key, for example R001?)

Answer (score 1):

We tried this at the project I'm currently working on. The best advice I can give you is to load and cache everything at startup (if newer). Roundtrips to DB to fetch individual labels kill performance.

Either build satellite assemblies in a bootstrapper, or cache translation in memory. In any case, try to make it transparent to WPF that you are hitting the DB. Using .NETs ResourceManager seems like the most logical choice for us.

There is a nice solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

Comment: Any specific example?

Comment: Of what? The link gives a better example than I can provide here.